# Will Front Load Washing Machine (BLDC motor) rated for 220V 60Hz work in another country with 220V 50Hz?

Tags: washing-machine, electric-motor, circuit

I currently have Daewoo DWC-ED1292 Washing Machine in the Middle East. It's rated for 220V 60Hz. I'm moving to another country with 220V 50Hz. I couldn't find any detailed manual for the machine online but it has Brushless DC Motor. As the input probably consists of a rectifier filter circuit which is less prone to frequency variation, will this appliance work on 50 Hz? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Daewoo customer service would be a better place to ask.  The difference in frequency is usually the hardest/expensive to adjust if needed.  Some devices if frequency does not matter will have it listed 50Hz/60Hz on the label, being listed as only 60hz might give problems at 50hz.

Answer (score 5):

### Check the nameplate

Every competent appliance has a placard or nameplate somewhere on it which states the power requirements.

That is the last word on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Washing machines, or any equipment, designed for 50Hz have components designed to work at that frequency. Same for equipment designed for 60Hz. If it is marked 50/60 Hz then it will work on both.

Sell it and buy another rated for the correct frequency.

You can get devices to change voltage and frquency but they are more expensive than the washing machine.

Search on here for questions like : I am moving abroad, can I take xxx with me? Or can I buy an xxx converter?

Comment: It's a BLDC motor. It's not being driven by the 60Hz AC line voltage.

Comment: @brhans so you guarantee it will work… luck OP.

Comment: No, I'm pointing out that your answer doesn't actually address the question. The BLDC motor in the OP's washing machine is not designed for 50Hz or 60Hz.

Comment: @brhans you and the downvoters make it look like I am wrong so the OP **can** use the washing machine…

Comment: Your answer is neither right nor wrong - it fails to address the question. I'm not disputing the fact that **AC** motors are designed for a particular operating frequency - I'm pointing out that this fact is irrelevant to the OP's situation.

Comment: Well, Solar Mike *did* say **if it is marked**.  That is the crux. Good enough for me!